# PHP pass variable through URL

Tags: php, url, variables

I understand how a PHP URL works - I think ... but I'm having problems getting the *actual* value of the variable to be passed in the example below.

#### Example

Note: I am adding the below form into a data cell (as part of a table being read via PHP).

```
$currentrowid = 1;

echo '<td>
  <div class="editdelete">
    <form action="phpindex.php?page=edit&thisrow=<?php echo $currentrowid;?>" method="post">
      <input type="submit" value="Edit" >
    </form>
  </div>
</td>';
```

... Some other section of code to read the URL output by the form above:

```
$val = $_POST['thisrow']; 
echo "the value is: " .$val; //Outputs "$currentrowid"
```

So, as you can see the code returns the actual **name** of the variable being passed, NOT the value of the variable being passed.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are already within a PHP block, you should not wrap your variable within `<?php ... ?>`. This will give you an error.

To make this work, you can choose 1 of 2 options:

1) String Concatenation:

```
echo '... <form action="phpindex.php?page=edit&thisrow='.$currentrowid.'" method="post"> ...';
```

2) Wrap your string in `"` (double quotes) instead of `'` (single quotes):

```
echo "... <form action=\"phpindex.php?page=edit&thisrow=$currentrowid\" method=\"post\"> ...";
```

Note that the second method forces you to escape all the double quotes inside of your string.

Comment: @Even: because this is elementary PHP code. I do not mean to be rude, but if you didn't know that, you should seriously read up on PHP.

Comment: @Evan: if you're getting an error that "there is an extra bracket", it must be in a part of the code you have not posted (although I do see that between `$currentrowid=10;` and `<form` there's no `?>`).

Comment: @Josesph this error only exists when I add in the PHP part. It may just be web expression. In which case ... perhaps the comment above may not have been as necessary as you had expected ...

Comment: @Joseph Please see my latest update, I think I left out an important part of the question - now it may make more sense as to why it is not working. I am not writing an HTML form, this form is being created using PHP.

Comment: @Evan: I completely rewrote my answer to reflect your (completely rewritten) question.

Comment: @Evan: why did you switch `$val = $_GET['thisrow'];` to `$val = $_POST['thisrow'];`? That won't work. See comments to @xdazz's answer.

Answer (score 1):

2 point.

1. `<form action="index.php?thisrow=<?php echo $currentrowid ?>"
   method="post">`
2. You should use $_POST not $_GET to get the post value.

Comment: He's not getting the `post` values from the `form`. He's getting the URL value, which he's correctly getting through `$_GET`.

Comment: @Joseph oops, you are right. Use $_GET to get query string value.

Answer (score 1):

As what was answered above,

```
<form action="index.php?thisrow=<?php echo $currentrowid; ?>" method="post">
```

is correct.
The reason behind this is you are passing HTML and you have to use an echo *from* php to output to the html. Otherwise you just get exactly what you put, which is $currentrowid.

Answer (score 1):

Not the easiest, but a quick way to solve your problem. Change your form method to get `method="get">`, then

```
$val = $_GET['thisrow'];
```